# Validity of Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In essence, IFT says: If f(x,y) is C' and f(a,b)=0, then f(x,y)=0 is an identity (f(g(y),y)=0).

But proof depends on f(x,y)=0 in a neighborhood of b. How do you know this? If you assume f(x,y)=0, the proof is circular (invalid).

Examples:

Baby Rudin 9.18 does not assume f(x,y)=0, but near the end of the proof it assumes f(x,y)=0: "If we now let W be a neighborhood of b such that (0,w) belongs to V if w belongs to W..." How do you know such a neighborhood exists?

Dieudonne begins a tortuous proof of IFT with "write the relation f(x,y)=0..." But given f(x,y), how do you know such a relation exists?

Classic authors such as Courant-Hilbert begin a geometric proof that f(x,y)=0 has a solution by drawing the curve f(x,y)=0, ie, assuming f(x,y)=0 exists.

**LINEARIZATION** Given f(x,y) you can write df=fxdx+fydy but you can't write df=0 unless you know f(x,y)=0 exists. **IMPLICIT DIFFERENTIATION** is not justified unless you know f(x,y)=0 exists, and you can't assume f(x,y)=0 to prove f(x,y)=0 exists.

Note: f(x,y) is often taken to mean fi(x1,..,xn,y1,..,ym), i=1 to n.

**QUESTION**: In all of the above, how do you know f(x,y)=0 exists?

Comment: I suggest you closely read again the sources you have cited. The assumption of the theorem is that $f(x,y)=0$ _in one single point_ (plus assumptions on differentiability and rank of the derivative, but that is not what you are addressing).

Comment: I quoted from Baby Rudin 9.18 and Dieudonne 10.2.1. Thought that was clear.

Comment: I have Rudin 3rd ed. but there it's 9.28. I don't see the sentence you quote.  We can't clear this up  for you without the full proof.

Comment: zhw: The edition you refer to says "We let  W be the set of all y belonging to R^m such that (0,y) belongs to V."  9.28 after (60). Essentially this says that f(x,y)=0 exists in a neighborhood of a,b. But how do you know this? Ref https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf   got there by googling "Rudin Principles of mathematical analysis" 3rd ed

Comment: @hartlw $W$ is, in the beginning, just a definition of a set defined by a certain property. As such it is possibly empty and does not imply the claim you seem to be seeing in it. The following sentences in the proof explain very clearly and stringently first why this set is not empty (there is one point in it for which it is known by construction) and then why it is even open (as a consequence of the inverse mapping theorem). I can only repeat my comment that you should read again with more care through your references.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit function theorem follows from the inverse function theorem as follows. 
I assume in your notation f'(a,b) means derivative wrt first variable (x).

Then F(x,y) =(f(x,y), y) has invertible Jacobian, so the inverse function theorem is satisfied. 
Let G be the inverse function to F (defined on a nbhd of F(a,b)=(0,b)). 
Then G(0,y) (as y varies) is the image of a smooth curve (the y-axis) under a diffeomorphism (or change of coordinates), which is therefore a smooth curve consisting of points where f(x,y)=0. And via G this curve is parametrized by y.

Comment: G(0,y) exists because F is invertible (see detailed proofs in the references). But how do you know (0,y) exists in a finite neighborhood of (0,b). As far as I can tell, it is assumed, ie, f(x,y)=0 is assumed.  the simple geometric "proof" shows that it does indeed exist, but where is it shown in the formal proof?

Comment: G(0,y) exists because F is invertible. But how do you know (0,y) exists in a finite neighborhood of (0,b)? 9 I gave a simple geometric proof, but wha is the formal, general proof?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to literal notation of Courant, Kaplan, Taylor, etc:

For F(x,y) satisfying conditions of IFT, Courant (D&I Calc II, 119) shows F(x,y) =0 has a solution y=f(x) in a neighborhood of (x0,y0). He says the extension to F(x,y...,u,v) is straight-forward:  F(x,y...,u,v)=0 has a solution v=f(x,y,..,u) in a neighborhood of P0.

Under conditions of IFT, Taylor (Adv Calc) shows F(x,y,z,u,v)=0 and G(x,y,z,u,v)=0 are satisfied in a neighborhood of P0 with u=f(x,y,z) and v=g(x,y,z).  He does this by first showing v=f(x,y,z,u) exists for F(x,y,z,u,v)=0 per above and then showing u=g(x,y,z) exists for G(x,y,z,f(x,y,z,u))= H(x,y,z,u)=0.

Finally, Taylor indicates the general case can be solved by induction.

Apostol and Rudin typify a different approach, presented abstractly, which led me to believe IFT was unproven because buried in the abstract proof was a false assumption, noted previously.